# Automate ID with Userform Entries - Excel

Tags: excel, userform

I have a Userform generating inputted data into a spreadsheet. In column H I have a space for a unique ID associated with each entry. I'm manually entering these ID's, but I'm looking for a way to automate this process. Is there a way for Excel to automatically input a unique ID after each Userform entry propagates data into the spreadsheet?

Comment: How would Excel know the unique user IDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use system date time.

In Excel Date & Time is stored in the form of serial number.

```
dim id as double
id = Int(CDbl(Now) * 100000) + i
```

test with msgbox, and you will get what you are looking for.

increase 0s in 100000 if you need more precise ID.

It will give you numeric ID. If you wish the ID to be alphanumeric then concatenate text with the number.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you